# Generate sequence of quarters backward in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to generate sequence of quarterly data backwards. For example if I input two arguments - 'Current Quarter' = Q2'20 and 'number of quarters' = 20 it should returns past 20 quarters data.

I know how to generate forward sequence of quarters (see below) but struggling how to do it backwards when I know the current quarter.

```
seq(as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="quarter", length.out = 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
seq(as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="-1 quarter", length.out = 10)
#  [1] "2020-10-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-01-01" "2019-10-01"
#  [6] "2019-07-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-01-01" "2018-10-01" "2018-07-01"
```

And if you want it in calendar order, just reverse it

```
rev(seq(as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="-1 quarter", length.out = 10))
#  [1] "2018-07-01" "2018-10-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-07-01"
#  [6] "2019-10-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-10-01"
```

This just uses base R. No `dplyr` needed.